# Why my scrapy script just scrape the first page and not the others?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some information on the website : http://quotes.toscrape.com/

But I cannot find a way to scrape all the pages, the script just scrape the first page, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my script so far :

```
import scrapy

from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = QuotetutorialItem()

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:   

            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tags'] = tags

            yield items

        next_page = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/'+ str(QuoteSpider.page_number) + '/'


        if QuoteSpider.page_number < 11:
            QuoteSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

And I type `scrapy crawl quote` in the terminal and it give me just the informations on the first page.

Any ideas ?

Thank you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is ok. Its extract all information of 10 pages. Please add

```
items['url'] = response.url
```

in your parse function. Then recheck its extract 10 pages information or not.

Comment: in for loop code block, for quotes in all_div_quotes: items['url'] = response.url

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out :)

Comment: KeyError: 'QuotetutorialItem does not support field: url'

Comment: in QuotetutorialItem class define a new field url.

Comment: items = QuotetutorialItem(url)
NameError: name 'url' is not defined   Maybe you meant 'start_urls' ?

Comment: in your items.py fiel . class QuotetutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()